# Prevent 404 of Author pages without posts

Tags: posts, pages, templates, author, 404-error

How do I prevent author archives without posts from 404ing?

Answer (score 1):

Why should you get redirected to the 404 page if you display an author archive without posts? This isn't the default behavior of WordPress.

For example, if you go to the following URL:

```
http://example.com/{permalink_base}/author/{author_name}
```

WordPress calls the `author.php` template inside your theme folder. There you have a loop which will return all posts of the author `{author_name}`. If this user has no posts, the loop will return nothing and will not redirect to the `404.php` template.

So you have to options:

1. Look in your themes `author.php` file what's going on there
2. Check if the user really exists in WordPress. You have to use the `username` and not the `display` or `nicename` inside the URL.

Comment: I just downloaded a fresh install of WP and Twenty Elven theme and tested this, it still doesn't work. All authors without posts get a 404. This is a plugin for this specific function: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/show-authors-without-posts/ but its old and no longer works with the current WP version

Comment: Look inside the `twentyeleven` folder and open the file `author.php`. There you can see an if-statement on line `15` which checks if the author has posts. If not (line `70`) a `Nothing Found` snippet will be displayed. Remove the if-statement and you will get a white/blank page.

Comment: okay gotcha, it was the "<?php else {" that made it 404 , but my theme doesn't have that else statement, is there anywhere else that wordpress is looking besides the author template?

Comment: If your theme doesn't have an `author.php` template, the  template from `twentyten` will be used. Copy the `author.php` file from `twentyeleven` to your theme and edit it like you want.